# How to transmit an AES encryption key?

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, blackberry-jde

On my Blackberry I am creating an AES key and encrypting data. I am then encrypting the AES key with RSA before sending to the client c#.net

The AES key is a byte array. How can I convert this to a string so that it can be encrypted by RSA and then decrypted on the .net side?

Do I have to convert to string?

I am transmitting the data via JSON. I guess my question is really how to transmit a but array in JSON? What character encoding would I use?

Thanks.

Comment: See `Convert.ToBase64String` & `Convert.FromBase64String` functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: RSA encrypts bytes, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, which is URL safe and relatively easy to visually inspect.  This takes a little more storage than Convert.ToBase64String, but shouldn't be an issue with a fixed width encryption key.

```
string MyKey = BitConverter.ToString(MyAESKey);  // dash removal is trivial here
```

OR

```
string MyKey = Convert.ToBase64String(MyAESKey);
```

**Code Sample**

```
byte[] a = new byte[256/8];
Random random = new Random();
random.NextBytes(a);

string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(a);
byte [] b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

if (a.SequenceEqual(b))
    // true


string c = BitConverter.ToString(a);

string[] c1 = c.Split('-');
byte[] d = new byte[arr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) d[i] = Convert.ToByte(c1[i], 16);

if (a.SequenceEqual(d))
    // true
```

Comment: Hmm, just tried that, thanks. But I have a problem. When I convert my 256 element byte array from java to Base64 it's longer than 256.. (290 or something). But when I convert it back in .NET it stays that length. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but when I do a base64 decode shouldn't the data be identical to before it was encoded? In my case it's not, the decoded data bytes array is longer than the original :-/

Comment: There are a couple reasons, the easiest in general is b/c you are representing your universe in in a base 64 system...so non printable characters need more encoding space.  What is most likely going on in this situation has to do with how the encoding actually works.  The method encodes each set of 3 bytes into 4 bytes and the output is always padded to be a multiple of 4. So your expansion formula will be ceil(n / 3) * 4, where n is the number of bytes in your input.

Comment: It's all good now, while examining my code to see what to post I spotted a typo. Thanks guys.

Comment: Why bother base64 encoding the input to RSA? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And why is your byte array 256 bytes long? That's enough to hold 8 256 bit keys.